# Three Mosquito Lures, Still Tons of Mosquitoes

Tags: mosquitoes

I have three mosquito lure traps on my property in Arizona. Two Stinger 21,000 sq. ft. lures that lure via Octenol and UV light, kill via electricity. And one Dynatrap 1-acre DT2000XL that lures via UV light, kills via entrapment.

They're all placed at least 25 feet from the home on different sides. I've got a well maintained pool but no standing water anywhere. The mosquitoes are overwhelming in the evening.

Wondering what else I can do. Perhaps a propane-burning machine like the  Mosquito Magnet? Are these lures non-effective?

Comment: I don't know what works, but I do know that these electric zappers are not effective against mosquitoes. What's worse, they are killing all kinds of pollinating insects, which are beneficial to your garden.

Comment: As far as I know the UV light is completely ineffective. Mosquitos are attracted to localized increases in carbon dioxide, the exhalations of blood sources.

Comment: True, the mosquito attractors I've seen use some sort of fuel burning machine to make CO2, and they *really* work.  Needless to say, the honeybees have no interest.

Answer (score 3):

Those instruments that use a light and electric grid to kill will kill everything but mosquitoes. Don;t waste your time and money. And they kill beneficial pollinating insects. Mosquitoes are attracted to the smell of humans  sweat or breath, not light or electric. I live in Texas where the humidity is high and the mosquitoes can stand up and whip a tom turkey. We have tried all kinds of remedies and the one that I have found that works the best, and it won't keep all of them away, just most, is Cutter Yard Fogger. It is about the best I have tried, and believe me, I have tried them all. It only is a temporary remedy and will have to be repeated as the summer goes.

Answer (score 1):

### Bat houses!

They cost less and blend in better than a lot of the high tech options, they last longer, have lower maintenance requirements, help support declining species, and provide entertainment at dusk. Each bat can eat hundreds to thousands of mosquitoes per night, and each house can accommodate lots of bats.

You can buy bat houses in a variety of shapes and sizes. Or if you like making things, there are plenty of DIY bat box plans available online.